# How to read the specific content from the webpage using the jsoup and jericho api for dynamic page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Iam right now using the jsoup api for the reading the content from the webpage but it is reading the all the content ,but i dont want all the content i want specific content for the dynamically given URL ,I also tryed in the Jericho api but its not solving the my problem .

Comment: post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

lets take this example

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.url.com").get();
Elements elem = doc.select("span.content");
System.out.println(elem.get(1).text());
System.out.println(elem.get(2).text());
```

if the url have this data

```
<html>
<body>

<span class="content">data one</span>

<span class="content">data two</span>

<a class="content">data three</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Now you'll get these 1st and 2nd elements only

```
<span class="content">data one</span>

<span class="content">data two</span>
```

**UPDATE**

```
//this is the help i can do to you bro
$search="data two";
$re = "/(.*)($search)(.*)/i";

//for example the doc object is having this html elements
$str = '<span class="content">data one</span>
<span class="content">data two</span>
<span class="content">data two</span>
<a class="content">data three</a>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>     <span class="content">data two</span>
    [1] =>     <span class="content">data two</span>
)
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/PmdZ5n)

Comment: But i dont know ther how many spans or divs or the tables because we arwe passing the url dynamically and which element having the data which we have to use also dont know , we have to read data dynamically  just passsing the url ,and that page contains the huge data but we dnt want all the data from that we are passing the some search words if that words match that contains then only we read that data ...thank u for reply

Comment: what is the procedure? do you submit any text to the url? or what? just give brief explanation

Comment: I just pass the url from the input text and pass the search key words in the other input text, submit the form then i want to generate a one flat file write the matched data into that file

Comment: matched data means? the tags which contains that data?

Comment: exactly like that only

Comment: see my updated answer,this is the only idea i've got :)